# Rendering geotiff raster on QGIS

Tags: qgis, geotiff-tiff, mosaic

I have various GeoTIFF raster image that I display on QGIS (3.2 or 3.4) - ortomoisaic created with agrisoft metashape

Sone raster (between 1 to 4 gb) are very slow to render/zoom on QGIS, while other (same size and even way bigger 10gb) render instantly and are extremely fast to zoom in/out

I looked at the informations panel in QGIS to spot any difference, but could not

What could the the reason for such a difference?

I do not recall changing anything in my mosaic creation process.

Comment: Do also the slow ones have overviews?

Comment: I checked and I was missign the overviews for the problematic GeoTIFF files.
I added them using GDAL and now it's a lot more faster to load in QGIS.